# How to pick a random image from a method to display?

Tags: java, javafx

My assignment wants us to ask a question with an image (using an image file I imported in my java project). How do I pick a random image file from my method? Example, in my 2nd line of code, I had an image file that displays a picture and that file is from "states_capitals" method below. How do I change it in a way where it would just show a random one of the file images I have listed?

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    ImageView us = new ImageView(new Image("file:///Users/flag.png"));

    Scene scene = new Scene (pane2, 600, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();   

    submit_button.setOnAction(e -> {
        correct_wrong();
    });
}

private void correct_wrong () {
    String index = answer_box.getText();   

    Map<String, String> mapStateCapitals = new HashMap<>(50);
    for (String[] stateCapital : states_capitals) {
        mapStateCapitals.put(stateCapital[0], stateCapital[1]);
    } 

    mapStateCapitals.forEach((state, capital) -> {    
        if (index.equalsIgnoreCase(capital)) {
            answer_result.appendText("Correct!");
        } else {
            answer_result.appendText("WRONG - The correct answer is " + capital);
        }
    });
}

private static String[][] states_capitals = {
        {"file:///Users/flag.png", "Siri"},
        {"file:///Users/flag.png2.png", "Juju"},
        {"file:///Users/flag.png3.png", "Cambodia"},           
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, you would simply create a `Random` object, and then using the `nextInt(int n)` method, create a random number between 0 and the length of the array, and reference the info in that array through the number you created. If you need help with that, see the [java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) for the `Random` class.

You may also want to consider grouping all the info for a question into a question class, to make it easier to manipulate, read, and access.